# Java, bukkit plugin, throws errors

Tags: java, bukkit

I created this plugin but it says error and I do not know how to solve it, for each answer, thank you.

Plugin is when the command sends a message prefix a suffix setting is in a config.

Source:

```
package cz.denowq.flatrov;


import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class flatrov extends JavaPlugin{
    
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        
        getLogger().info("[FlatRov] Načítávaní pluginu na verzi 1.0.1");
        
        getConfig().options().copyDefaults();
        saveConfig();
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        
        getLogger().info("[FlatRov] Byl vypnut!");
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        String text = "";
        if (player.hasPermission("flatrov.zprava")) {
            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("zprava")) {
                if((text = getConfig().getString("flatrav.zprava.prikaz")).length() != 0) {
                    String message = joinArgs(args);
                     Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "" + getConfig().getString("flatrav.zprava.prefix") + " " + getConfig().getString("flatrav.zprava.suffix") + message));
                } else {
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + " Použij /zprava <zprava> pro napsání zpravy!");
                }
            }
        } else {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + " Nemáš povolený používat tento příkaz!");
        }
        return false;
    }
        
    private String joinArgs(String[] args) {
        String separator = ""; // empty on first iteration
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String arg : args) {
            builder.append(separator).append(arg);
            separator = " "; // space after each arg
        }
        return builder.toString(); // return result
    }
    //String message = joinArgs(args);
}
```

Error:

```
[20:04:14] [Server thread/ERROR]: null
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'zprava' in plugin FlatRov v1.0.1
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:181) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:767) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1016) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:846) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:28) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PacketPlayInChat.handle(PacketPlayInChat.java:65) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:184) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ServerConnection.c(ServerConnection.java:81) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:731) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.DedicatedServer.v(DedicatedServer.java:289) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.u(MinecraftServer.java:584) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:490) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cz.denowq.flatrov.flatrov.onCommand(flatrov.java:36) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    ... 13 more
[20:04:25] [Server thread/INFO]: DenOwq issued server command: /zprava test
[20:04:25] [Server thread/ERROR]: null
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'zprava' in plugin FlatRov v1.0.1
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:181) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:767) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1016) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:846) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:28) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PacketPlayInChat.handle(PacketPlayInChat.java:65) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:184) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ServerConnection.c(ServerConnection.java:81) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:731) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.DedicatedServer.v(DedicatedServer.java:289) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.u(MinecraftServer.java:584) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:490) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cz.denowq.flatrov.flatrov.onCommand(flatrov.java:36) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1564]
    ... 13 more
```

EDIT: remove config

Comment: This looks like it is a highly specialized question that deals with interfacing with the Minecraft Bukkit plugin.  Such questions I think are better suited for the Bukkit forums as opposed to here.  Only thing I can suggest is to debug it in your development environment by setting up mock data and passing a command through to see where it errors.  From the looks of it, you are not accounting for a case in which an exception is thrown, such as the player object not being extracted correctly.

Comment: `(text = getConfig().getString("flatrav.zprava.prikaz")).length()` appears to be causing the NPE, please make sure your `config.yml` file has a value associated with that key.

Comment: @Vizkos actually it's just an NPE that gets called from some internal methods.

Answer (score 1):

You seemed to have either learned bukkit 2 years ago or you are just using bad practices because around 2 years ago bukkit started automatically logging when your plugin was enabled or disabled.

You do not need to log that your plugin is enabled / disabled since bukkit already does that.

This code can be simplified

```
getConfig().options().copyDefaults();
saveConfig();
```

can be written as

```
saveDefaultConfig();
```

Next, in the command handler you shouldn't check for the permission there. You should add the permission node to the command in your plugin.yml

You should specify a default value when reading the configuration. Since the key doesn't exist it is returning null when you try accessing it with getString(). Use something like this instead.

```
getString("flatrav.zprava.prikaz"), "")
```

This method will return an empty string if it doesn't exist.

Also, your joinArgs() function appends an extra space to the output.

A quick fix to that after appending all the elements together use something like

```
sb.set length(sb.get length - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your stack trace shows an error on line 36. This is the line containing your first config call: `getConfig().getString("flatrav.zprava.prikaz")`.

If your config does now contain a value at `flatrav.zprava.prikaz`, the method will return null. In Java, you can not run methods on a null value. You store this null as `text` which is perfectly fine, but the second you call `.length()` on that null value, you get a NullPointerException. To fix this, you should check if `text == null` or change `getConfig().getString("flatrav.zprava.prikaz")` to `getConfig().getString("flatrav.zprava.prikaz", "")` which will make the method return an empty string if it fails to find anything at `" flatrav.zprava.prikaz"`.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the problem here

```
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

    Player player = (Player) sender;
    String text = "";
```

The problem is that you are immediately casting your sender to type `Player` without checking if the `sender` is a `player`. The problem will only show up if someone sends a command from the console or a plugin uses the server as a `CommandSender` when dispatching a command. To fix this just add an if statement that encompasses the rest of the method.

Also if you `return false` from the `onCommand` method the sender will receive a message from the server about incorrect/invalid usage of the command. Try returning `true` unless you want them to be sent this message

```
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

    if (sender instanceof Player) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        String text = "";
        if (player.hasPermission("flatrov.zprava")) {
            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("zprava")) {
                if((text = getConfig().getString("flatrav.zprava.prikaz")).length() != 0) {
                    String message = joinArgs(args);
                    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "" + getConfig().getString("flatrav.zprava.prefix") + " " + getConfig().getString("flatrav.zprava.suffix") + message));
                } else {
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + " Použij /zprava <zprava> pro napsání zpravy!");
                }
            }
        } else {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + " Nemáš povolený používat tento příkaz!");
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```